# android: how to delete a line from sql via ListView?

Tags: android, android-activity

I managed to show a list from sqllite, now I want that when the user click on the item, the item will be deleted. the problem is that the item's ID number from the sql is different from the listview's ID. so how can I delete the selected item?

I mean this id:
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,**int position, long id**)
is different from the item's ID from the sqllite.

thank you for help

```
    Cursor resultSet = db.rawQuery("Select * from list ORDER BY `ID` DESC",null);
    resultSet.moveToFirst();


      final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylistData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String[] columnames = new String[] {"C1", "C2", "C3"};
    int[] columnsR = new int[] {R.id.column1, R.id.column2, R.id.column3};


    int x=0;
    while(resultSet.moveToNext()){
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String d_weight = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("weight"));
        String d_date = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("date"));
        String d_id = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("ID"));

        x=0;
        map.put(columnames[x],d_weight);
        x++;
        map.put(columnames[x],d_date);
        x++;
        map.put(columnames[x],d_id);

        mylistData.add(map);
     }


        SimpleAdapter arrayAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylistData, R.layout.row,columnames , columnsR);
            listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);




       listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
            {

                     // how to delete? =[ 
            }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it not be easier to make an object that you fill with the data from your sql query for each entry? Then you just populate the listview with a list of these objects, which means that when one of the objects get clicked on the id will be stored inside the object. Then **int position** would have the same value as the position in your list of objects.

How does that sound?